# Summarize temporal information into a dynamic matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize

I have a data frame like `df`:

```
id <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E")
year <- c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2005", "2007", "2006", "2007", "2008")
value <- 1:12
df <- data.frame(id, year, value)
```

I want to convert `df` into a matrix `id_observed` where columns count how many id's are observed for the first time, by year. Rows count how many ids "survive" to the consecutive year:

```
id_observed <- matrix(c(3,2,3,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
#First observed id's (by columns), consecutive id's observations (by rows)
colnames(id_observed) <- c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008")
rownames(id_observed) <- c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008")
id_observed
```

The same idea applies to generate matrix `value_observed` taking the information from `value`. Where columns count the aggregated value of id's that are observed for the first time, by year. Rows count the aggregated value of the  ids that "survived" to the consecutive year:

```
value_observed <- matrix(c(14,8,19,4,0,10,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
#First observed value (by columns), consecutive value's observations (by rows)
colnames(value_observed) <- c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008")
rownames(value_observed) <- c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008")
value_observed
```

Any clue on how to build matrices `id_observed`, and `value_observed` in an automatic way?

Comment: what does the gap for id = C mean?  I.e. has rows for  2005 and 2007., but not 2006?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this function, `get_matrix()`, which leverages tidyverse approach to loop over unique years, creating the data for each year, binding the rows, and then pivoting wider

```
library(tidyverse)

get_matrix <- function(df, type=c("value","id")) {
  res = lapply(unique(df$year), function(y) {
    d = df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(min(year)==y) %>% group_by(year)
    if(type == "value") d = summarize(d,n=sum(value))
    else d = summarize(d,n=n())
    d = mutate(d,y=y)
    if(nrow(d)==0) return(tibble(year=y, n=0, y=y)) else return(d)
  })
  bind_rows(res) %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = year,names_from = y,values_from = n,values_fill = 0)    
}
```

Usage

```
get_matrix(df, type="value")
```

Output

```
  year  `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008`
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2005      14      0      0      0
2 2006       8     10      0      0
3 2007      19     11      0      0
4 2008       4      0      0     12
```

Usage

```
get_matrix(df, type="id")
```

Output

```
  year  `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008`
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2005       3      0      0      0
2 2006       2      1      0      0
3 2007       3      1      0      0
4 2008       1      0      0      1
```

### Update:

data.table option

```
setDT(df)[, year:=as.integer(year)]
syears = unique(df$year)
df = df[, y:=min(year), by = id][, .SD[,.N, year], by=y]
dcast(
  rbind(df,data.table(y=setdiff(syears, unique(df$y)))[,`:=`(year=y,N=0)]),
  year~y, value.var="N"
)
```

Output:

```
    year  2005  2006  2007  2008
   <int> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:  2005     3    NA    NA    NA
2:  2006     2     1    NA    NA
3:  2007     3     1     0    NA
4:  2008     1    NA    NA     1
```

Comment: Excellent! How would you overcome the second outcome, related to the **value**?

Comment: instead of `ungroup() %>% count(year)`, we would do `group(year) %>% summarize(n=sum(value))`

Comment: I've cleaned it up for you, in functional form

Comment: My data is very large (+10 million) so the computation is very slow. Do you have any solution for ```data.table()```?

Comment: @vog, I've added a data.table option  / for now, just for the first approach, but you can adapt it easily for t- perhaps you can see if it helps you?  If you have 10 million rows, you might rethink if this type of sparse matrix is actually what you need.